# Deleting std::map of functions

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, std, stdmap

I am trying to delete the following map:

```
typedef bool (myClass::*func)(std::vector<std::string> &args);
typedef std::map<std::string, func> myMap;
myMap map; //map of functions in the class 'myClass'

void deleteMap()
{
    for(myMap::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it)
    {
        delete it->second; //compiler says it->second is non-pointer type
        map.erase(it);
    }
}
```

'map' is mapping a string to a function in the class 'myClass', and this function takes a vector of strings in its parameter.

In my attempt to delete this map I am trying to delete the pointer to the member function, then erase the iterator itself. The compiler says that it->second must be a pointer type. In the typdef 'func' is a pointer to myClass:: so why am I getting this error?

Is this the appropriate way to delete a map of functions?

Comment: You did new the member functions?

Comment: Why do you want to call delete on the pointers?

Comment: It appears that the correct way to delete that map is to exit the function.

Comment: Even if there was no compilation error, the shown code is buggy, and is guaranteed to result in a crash due to undefined behavior after incrementing a deleted iterator.

Comment: You are trying to **delete** the memory that represents a **member function** of `myClass`. Just take a short moment to think about the implications of this! `delete` only works for memory that has been dynamically allocated on the heap, (member) functions are all in the static read-only part of memory. Simply never try to delete a function pointer. Emptying the map using `erase` or `clear` should be enough

Comment: Just because we *can* store a map of member function pointers doesn't mean there is a good reason to.

Comment: You pass `delete` a pointer to the thing you want to delete. What is the thing you want to delete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand some concepts here. You use `delete`/`delete[]` to release memory which has been allocated by `new`/`new[]`, respectively.

Here, you have a `std::map` that stores pointer-to-member-function values. There is no memory allocated on the heap with `new`, so you do not have to free the memory using `delete` at all.

In addition to that, you do not need to use [`std::map::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) for every element. Instead, you might use either [`std::map::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear)
to clear the `std::map`, or just let the destructor of `std::map` release the contents automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `delete` a member pointer, because it is part of a class instance.

You haven't posted code where you add an element to `myMap`, but such code cannot create the member pointer with a `new` on something of type `func` which indicates that the `delete` is wrong, because every `delete` must be matched by a `new`.

You can simply call `myMap.clear()` to delete `myMap`'s content.

Answer (score 1):

> In my attempt to delete this map I am trying to delete the pointer to the member function,

That is not allowed by the language. You can call `delete` on an object pointer only.

Think of this.

```
int (*fptr)(const char *lhs, const char *rhs ) = &std::strcmp;

 // Does it make any sense at all?
 // What would you expect the run time to do with this?
delete fptr;
```

Your function can be very simple. You can just clear the map.

```
void deleteMap()
{
   map.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes *pointer* might refer to different kinds of pointers as a whole but often, such as in this case in particular, it means specifically a *data pointer*. Your pointer is a *member function pointer* and as such it is not such *pointer* type that your compiler is referring to.

Only data pointers may be passed to the `delete` operator, otherwise the program is ill-formed. More specifically, you may only pass a pointer value that was returned by the `new` operator. In other words, `delete` is used to deallocate dynamic memory that you have allocated with `new`.

`new` operator can never return a (member) function pointer, so your function pointers could not possibly have been returned by `new`.

> Is this the appropriate way to delete a map of functions?

No. You cannot "delete" the functions that the map points to.

`map::erase` removes the function pointer from the map, but incrementing that iterator after having it erased has undefined behaviour. So, erasing in a loop can not be achieved as simply as you've attempted.

If you want to remove all pointers, it is simpler to just call `map::clear`. On the third hand, all of the contents are automatically destroyed when the map itself is destroyed.

Objects with static storage duration, such as your map, are destroyed automatically at the end of the program, and you cannot delete them yourself.